# Possible to slipstream Visual Studio 2010 into a Windows 7 install?

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2010, windows-installation, slipstream

Is there a way to merge VS2010 into a Windows install DVD so that it is ready for use the first time Windows boots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [sysprep](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722413%28WS.10%29.aspx), it allows you to install windows and all software, and then prepare the system for imaging and distribution.

When you arrive at windows 7 out of the box, instead of filling out the fields press ctrl+shift+F3. You'll enter audit mode and can perform whatever installs you need and configure the computer account as well as the default user account.

Every time you boot into this mode sysprep's dialog box will appear asking you what to do. when you're ready select reseal and on next power on boot from your favorite imaging software and create the image. You can then drop it wherever you need to.

Comment: Sysprep works on the installed image instead of repackaging things into the base image on the DVD. I think the poster wants everything back on the DVD.

Comment: yeah but I guessed he might want to use another method. I find wims kinda slow...

Comment: Installing OS, then Visual Studio, then sysprepping and imaging back to ISO seems like the closest match even if it is a PITA.

It would be ready if Microsoft had an OS downloads page with pre-installed software options, then you just enter your keys at startup like you do for the OS.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the ISO with this freeware tool http://www.rt7lite.com/.
It also supports integrating applications into the ISO.

Comment: Will test if I can integrate VS2010 into the install media using this tool.

Comment: @TomPaine Yeah, it worked succesful for smaller tools like firefox or stuff, never tried something big as MSVS though.

Comment: I've checked it out, rt7lite can only run command line executables with switches. I can probably pack the ISO up somehow but it's not integration - I could perform the same duty with a script.